# Changing an specific numeric error in a given variable

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to change all the zeros (0) and 36.1 in a given variable to another number.

To give you a better picture, this is what i tried to do:

```
transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL <- ifelse(transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0,36.1) & transacciones_diarias$COD_TIPOMOV == "VENTA",
                                                 transacciones_diarias$MONTO_TIPOCAMBIOCOL-0.01,
                                                    ifelse(transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0,36.1) & transacciones_diarias$COD_TIPOMOV == "COMPRA",
                                                           transacciones_diarias$MONTO_TIPOCAMBIOCOL+0.01,
                                                           transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL),
                                                 transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL)
```

The error is:

```
Error in ifelse(transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0, 36.1) &  : 
  unused argument (transacciones_diarias$TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL)
```

Here is some sample data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Pictures of data are not helpful because we cannot copy/paste the data for testing. See the link I provided for how to share data in a reproducible format. If you got errors with your method, be sure to include those. Also it seems like you are using variables like `TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL ` without referring to the data.frame name `transacciones_diarias$` which generally doesn't work unless you are using `transform()` or `dplyr::mutate()`

Comment: Im trying to get some sample data, but i cant. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want with dplyr::case_when.  This should work as desired, but I can't test without data. Hope it helps.

```
new_df <- df %>%
  mutate(TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL = case_when(
    !TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0, 36.1) ~ TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL, # if values aren't 0 or 36.1, keep them.
    TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0, 36.1) & COD_TIPOMOV == 'COMPRA' ~ MONTO_TIOPCAMBIOCOL -0.01, 
    TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL %in% c(0, 36.1) & COD_TIPOMOV == 'VENTA' ~ MONTO_TIOPCAMBIOCOL +0.01
    ))
```

EDIT: This will add/subtract 0.01 from the MONTO column based on the COD_TIPOMOV value.

Comment: I dont want an specific number, I need it to be:
TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL + 0.01
or
TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL - 0.01.
I tried to edit the the code and it just returned +0.01 or -0.01 once I modified it.

Comment: TIPO_CAMBIO_POOL = 0 in those places, so that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Im supposed to sum it to MONTO_TIPOCAMBIOCOL. Thanks!